# Remove OneDrive from File Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, onedrive, windows-10

I'd like to get rid of the OneDrive option from the navigation panel of File Explorer. Preview-era articles I've found recommend registry tweaks, which is rather inelegant, and I'm hoping there is a better way to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gpedit.msc -> Local Computer Policy\Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\OneDrive

Enable "Prevent the usage of OneDrive for file storage". This will disable and remove everything after a restart

Comment: any thoughts for Home version users?   I don't think we have GroupPolicy

Comment: @MikeM [There are ways to manually install the Group Policy Editor on Windows Home Edition.](https://superuser.com/a/1018146/358766)

Answer (score 4):

The above answer doesn't work for Home users as they do not have gpedit.msc. I do understand you weren't looking for Registry fixes but this appear to be the only way. (You can stop OneDrive from booting but it doesn't remove it completely)

Take a look at [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3f45ix/easy_way_to_uninstall_onedrive_if_you_arent_using/) thread at Reddit

**EDIT**:
Pasted the Reddit post incase something changes

--

If you want to remove OneDrive **permanently**, do the following:

Create a text file by opening Notepad

Go on the [following link](http://pastebin.com/zw70xK8e) and copy/paste the code into the text file:

```
@echo off
cls

set x86="%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OneDriveSetup.exe"
set x64="%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\OneDriveSetup.exe"

echo Closing OneDrive process.
echo.
taskkill /f /im OneDrive.exe > NUL 2>&1
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > NUL 2>&1

echo Uninstalling OneDrive.
echo.
if exist %x64% (
%x64% /uninstall
) else (
%x86% /uninstall
)
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > NUL 2>&1

echo Removing OneDrive leftovers.
echo.
rd "%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive" /Q /S > NUL 2>&1
rd "C:\OneDriveTemp" /Q /S > NUL 2>&1
rd "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive" /Q /S > NUL 2>&1
rd "%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft OneDrive" /Q /S > NUL 2>&1 

echo Removeing OneDrive from the Explorer Side Panel.
echo.
REG DELETE "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}" /f > NUL 2>&1
REG DELETE "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}" /f > NUL 2>&1

pause
```

Then save as RemoveOneDrive.bat and exit

Run the script with admin rights and One Drive will be gone

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/157730) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. That way, should the linked page ever change or become invalid for any reason, the answer will still be useful to visitors to Super User. Link-only answers, or answers which overly rely on external resources to be understood, may become invalid if the cited resource ever is changed or becomes unavailable.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Clear!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Ramhound That's why I edited the post

Comment: You just edited it....to what it should have been originally

Comment: What if we just want to remove OneDrive from Windows Explorer without completely uninstalling it?