# How do I get rid of OneDrive completely?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, uninstall, onedrive

First, I've tried https://superuser.com/a/947575/247842 which is using gpedit.msc
Second, I've tried https://superuser.com/a/949571/247842 which is using SysWOW64\OneDriveSetup.exe to uninstall, and deleting of some left over registry keys.

I've rebooted.

And still every time I open explorer, I've got this big p.o.s. banner that makes me absolutely hate even using windows.

[image: http://imgur.com/a/jPchz]

How do I get rid of this and OneDrive completely?

Comment: ok, I think I know what you see. those are advertisements in Explorer. I posted how to disable them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [this script to remove Onedrive](https://www.antary.de/2015/07/12/windows-10-onedrive-komplett-entfernen/) completely:

```
@echo off
cls

set x86="%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OneDriveSetup.exe"
set x64="%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\OneDriveSetup.exe"

echo OneDrive Prozess beenden
echo.
taskkill /f /im OneDrive.exe > NUL 2>&1
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > NUL 2>&1

echo OneDrive deinstallieren
echo.
if exist %x64% (
%x64% /uninstall
) else (
%x86% /uninstall
)
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > NUL 2>&1

echo OneDrive Überreste entfernen
echo.
rd "%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive" /Q /S > NUL 2>&1
rd "C:\OneDriveTemp" /Q /S > NUL 2>&1
rd "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive" /Q /S > NUL 2>&1
rd "%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft OneDrive" /Q /S > NUL 2>&1 

echo OneDrive im Datei Explorer entfernen
echo.
REG DELETE "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}" /f > NUL 2>&1
REG DELETE "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}" /f > NUL 2>&1
REG DELETE "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}\ShellFolder" /f > NUL 2>&1
REG DELETE "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}\ShellFolder" /f > NUL 2>&1

pause
```

I think you miss the last step to remove the 4 registry entries.

Ok, you seam to use an Insider Build and [what you see are Tips/Ads in Explorer](http://www.theverge.com/2017/3/9/14872464/windows-10-onedrive-ads-inside-file-explorer). To disable it, open Explorer options and uncheck the entry "Show sync provider notifications"

[image]